# Why does this throw an undefined exception?

Tags: javascript

```
var x = []
var y = []
x.forEach (y.push)
```

Line 3 will throw `Uncaught TypeError: Array.prototype.push called on null or undefined` if x is non-empty.

```
var x = [ 1 ]
var y = []
x.forEach (y.push)
```

Notes:
x.forEach passes 3 arguments to y.push, 1 of which is y. Explicitly doing this does not cause an error.

```
y.push (1, 1, y)
```

Wrapping y.push inside an anonymous function will prevent the error, even if all arguments are passed through. As far as I can tell, it doesn't matter the number of arguments applied.

```
x.forEach (function (a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j) {
  y.push (a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j)
})
```

Explicitly calling y.push with null and undefined will not cause the error, even when attempting to trick it with additional optional parameters.

```
y.push (1, 2, 3, undefined, 5, 6, null, 7, 8)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because when you pass `y.push` to `.forEach()`, it loses the `y` context and you get just the push method with an inappropriate value for `this` when `.forEach()` calls it.

You can make it work by binding the object like this:

```
var x = [];
var y = [];
x.forEach (y.push.bind(y)); // push the x items into y
```

This, of course has other issues in that `forEach()` passes more than one argument which `.push()` will pick up.  So, you really can't successfully use this short form to combine arrays.

---

When you do something like

```
var y = [];
var m = y.push;
```

At this point, `m === Array.prototype.push`.  There is no object bound to the method in `m`.  This is a subtlety of Javascript that trips up many, but when you really understand what's going in internally, it does start to make sense.

`.push()` is just a property on an object, so when you put that property into a variable or pass it as an argument, it's just its own value at that point an no longer has any association with the object that you got it from.

So, to use it appropriately after you grabbed it from an object, you have to bind it to an object with something like `.call()`, `.apply()` or `.bind()` in order to use it on that object.

---

If all you're trying to do is to copy all the x elements onto the end of y, there are a number of ways to do that.  You can do this:

```
y.push.apply(y, x);
```

Since `.push()` takes more than one argument, you can just pass the whole `x` array to `.push()`.

In ES6, this is even easier:

```
y.push(...x);
```

Comment: Such a quick response. This seems to be it. Very curious that the instance reference isn't bound in a closure like other variables would be. I'll accept the answer when I can in several minutes. Thank you

Comment: @user3288049 - no closure was created in your first code example.  You just passed a function reference to `x.forEach()` - that's all that happened.  `x.forEach()` then called that function reference like a normal function and since it wasn't meant to be called as a normal function (it's meant to be called as a method call), it did not work properly.

Comment: I added ES5 and ES6 solutions to the original problem.